# Runtime type checking of @testable imported objects in tests

Tags: swift, tdd

I've been bitten by this problem on a few projects now and so am keen to find a good solution.

Consider the following scenario:

- I've defined an object in my app target called `MyObject`, which is used in `MyBusinessLogicObject`.
- in `MyBusinessLogicObjectTests`, I have `@testable import`ed my app's package but need to conditionally cast after pulling an object out of a non-generic collection:

  ```
  import XCTest
  @testable import MyApp

  class MyBusinessLogicObjectTests: XCTestCase {

      var bizLogicObject: MyBusinessLogicObject!

      // setUp() etc.

      func testStuff() {
          guard let result = bizLogicObject.someOrderedCollectionProperty.first as? MyObject else {
              XCTFail()
              return
          }

          // more test code here
      }
  }
  ```

**The problem is, even though I can see the type of `bizLogicObject.someOrderedCollectionProperty.first` is `MyObject` the conditional cast fails.**

I understand this is because when you `@testable import` like this, all your types from your app get duplicated. Hence the runtime check actually ends up being against two different types, which is why it fails.

Does anyone know how to get conditional casts in tests to pass, where you need to cast to a type defined within your app?

Comment: have you found solution? I am also facing this issue..

Answer (score -1):

Ensure that `MyObject` is only included in the app target, not in both the app target AND test target.